# Create folders with names of moved files with Python

Tags: python

I am starting to use Python and I have some doubts that I hope you can help me:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob


source = r"C:\Users\Pasanus\Downloads\Captuars"


destHuman = r"H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Humans"
destDragon = r"H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Dragons"

for Archivos in glob.glob(source + "\\*Human*"):
    shutil.move(Archivos, destHuman)


for Archivos in glob.glob(source + "\\*Dragon*"):
    shutil.move(Archivos, destDragon)
```

I have created this code that makes any file containing X words, move to one folder or another. So far so good, everything works correctly.

But now I would like to create folders in the destinations with the names of the files that have just been moved, and if there are 2 or more files with the same name, they will be saved in the same folder.

Thank you very much, I hope you can help me.

Comment: How can there be 2 files with the same name? In most file systems the full path of every file must be unique

Comment: Cloud you please add more details. like : Sample file names, Expected folder structure, Current folder structure

Comment: To give an example, sometimes I have a .rar file called "Dragon - Field Test" and next to it there is a .jpg file with the same name (as they are files with different extensions they can be called the same). So what I would like is for the script to create a Folder called "Dragon - Field Test" in the destination folder, and move both files in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a couple of days of testing, I've managed to come up with this:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
import errno


source = r"C:\Users\Pasanus\Downloads\Captuars"

destArtisan = r"H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Artisan Guild\New"
destEpic = r"H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Epic Minis\New"



for i in glob.glob(source + "\\*Artisan Guild*"):
    if i:
        for Archivos in glob.glob(source + "\\*Artisan Guild*"):
            try:
                os.mkdir(destArtisan)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                    raise

            shutil.move(Archivos, destArtisan)

        print(os.listdir(destArtisan))
        listaArtisan = os.listdir(destArtisan)
        os.rename(destArtisan, r'H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Artisan Guild\\' + listaArtisan[0])
    else:
        continue

for i in glob.glob(source + "\\*Epic Miniatures*"):
    if i:
        for Archivos in glob.glob(source + "\\*Epic Miniatures*"):
            try:
                os.mkdir(destEpic)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                    raise

            shutil.move(Archivos, destArtisan)

        print(os.listdir(destEpic))
        listaEpic = os.listdir(destEpic)
        os.rename(destEpic, r'H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Epic Miniatures\\' + listaEpic[0])
    else:
        continue
```

I don't know if it's well formulated, or if it's elegant, but working works. The code checks if inside the Source folder there are any files containing the keywords, and if there are, it creates a new folder, moves the files into it, and renames that folder with the first name it finds inside it.
Now I only have to repeat it 23 times for 23 keywords, but I think it's ok, no?

Next step would be to create an executable in the Source folder that does all that without having to open Python.